# plotting from data frame with 2 fixed variables

Tags: r, plot

Consider the following:

```
set.seed(1)
RandData <- rnorm(100,sd=20)
Locations <- rep(c('England','Wales'),each=50)
today <- Sys.Date()
dseq <- (seq(today, by = "1 days", length = 100))

Date <- as.POSIXct(dseq, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

Final <- cbind(Loc = Locations, Doy = as.numeric(format(Date,format = "%j")), Temp = RandData)
```

In this example how is it possible to produce two plots in the same figure window, where the first plot shows the temperature in England against Doy and the second shows temperature in Wales against Doy?

Comment: It is a bit ambiguous as to whether you want 2 plots in one window or the two data sets drawn on top of one another in the same window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your data is a character matrix. Better if the `Final` object is created via:

```
Final <- data.frame(Loc = Locations,
                    Doy = as.numeric(format(Date,format = "%j")),
                    Temp = RandData)
```

With that, the code below draws two plots on the one window, side by side. I use the formula interface to `plot()` to make use of it's `subset` argument, which works like the `subset()` function.

```
ylab <- "Temperature"
xlab <- "Day of year"

layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
plot(Temp ~ Doy, data = Final, subset = Loc == "England", main = "England",
     ylab = ylab, xlab = xlab)
plot(Temp ~ Doy, data = Final, subset = Loc == "Wales", main = "Wales",
     ylab = ylab, xlab = xlab)
layout(1)
```

Which produces this plot:

[image: england wales temperatures]

If you want them both on the same scale then we modify it a bit:

```
ylab <- "Temperature"
xlab <- "Day of year"
xlim <- with(Final, range(Doy))
ylim <- with(Final, range(Temp))
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
plot(Temp ~ Doy, data = Final, subset = Loc == "England", main = "England",
     ylab = ylab, xlab = xlab, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
plot(Temp ~ Doy, data = Final, subset = Loc == "Wales", main = "Wales",
     ylab = ylab, xlab = xlab, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
layout(1)
```

which produces this version of the plot

[image: england wales temp with same scaling]

For a line-plot you'd need to get the data in `Doy` order and then add `type = "l"` to the `plot()` calls.

For completeness, @Justin has shown how to use one of the high level plotting packages to achieve something similar but with less user-effort via **ggplot2**. The **lattice** package is another major high-level plotting package in R. You can achieve the same plot using lattice via:

```
require(lattice)
xyplot(Temp ~ Doy | Loc, data = Final, type = c("l","p")
```

The latter produces

[image: england wales temp v3 via lattice]

Use `type = "p"` for just points and `type = "l"` for just lines. As you can see, the higher-level packages make producing these plots a bit easier than with the base graphics package.

Comment: There is the lattice code I show but unless you are familiar with it you'll have similar problems to **ggplot2**. For base graphics, no; you are responsible for writing all the code required to produce the individual plots. I suppose you could write a loop but that will involve as much code-writing as the two calls to plot.

Answer (score 0):

by using cbind to create your data, they are all coerced to `character`.  instead use `data.frame()`

```
Final <- data.frame(Loc = Locations, 
                    Doy = as.numeric(format(Date,format = "%j")), 
                    Temp = RandData)
```

`ggplot` does things like this very nicely.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Final, aes(x=Doy, y=Temp)) + geom_path() + facet_wrap( ~ Loc)
```

Or you can use coloring:

```
ggplot(Final, aes(x=Doy, y=Temp, color=Loc)) + geom_path()
```

Comment: Both of these work great, I am not that familiar with using ggplot though, is there a way of removing the gray background from the plots?